# How to send Python Post Request to Dialogflow to Import/Export Agents

Tags: python, post, dialogflow-es

I want to upload an Agent to Dialogflow. And Export it afterwards. But this should be easier once the uploading process is clear.

I know how to send a normal POST Request with Python to the Dialogflow API and receive an answer. 
But I am not getting any smarter from this Documentation.
[Dialogflow Import Agent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent/import)

How are you supposed to package your POST Request with your Zip file?
I am totally clueless.

My normal Post Request looks like this:

```
url = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 
  'Bearer API-KEY', 'Accept': 
    'application/json'}

payload = {
  "contexts": [
    "shop"
  ],
  "lang": "en",
  "query": "I need apples",
  "sessionId": "12345",
  "timezone": "America/New_York"
}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

How are you supposed to package the parameter to import the .ZIP File into Dialogflow.

The fields are described below but o no prevail for me :(.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the zip as `bytes` string?

General comment: Have you considered the V2 API? It made my code much shorter. I found that documentation is still lacking, but useful examples are available on Github: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/dialogflow/cloud-client

Comment: Hey, good idea, I will try that.
I think you also need " OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs" to import/export the data.
I tried the examples, as the import/export calls only work with V2 API. But felt like a degenerate trying the examples :D